# How to improve code using reduce instead two loops?

Tags: javascript

I tried to improve code using reducing:

```
private getAllRegistryObjects(registry: RegistryGeneric) {
    const registryLayerItemGeneric = [];
    registry.RegistryLayers.forEach((layer) => {
        layer.items.forEach((item) => {
            registryLayerItemGeneric.push(item);
        });
    });

    return registryLayerItemGeneric;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
return registry.RegistryLayers.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue.concat(currentValue.items.flat());
}, [])
```

But it returns me empty array

Comment: Try asking an actual question. What is your input data set. What is your expected output data set. You can't just throw some random terms like reduce in there and hope people will magically understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works:

```js
var registry = {RegistryLayers: [
{ items: ['some', 'item'] },
{ items: ['other', 'things'] }
]};
var res = registry.RegistryLayers.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue.concat(currentValue.items.flat());
}, []);
console.log(res)
```

says:

```js
['some', 'item', 'other', 'things']
```

To reduce need to repeatedly extend/copy the array, you can use `flatMap` instead if you just want them all joined up:

```js
return registry.RegisteryLayers.flatMap((x) => x.items.flat());
```